# Counting number classes from each div in jquery php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have div with class name `bus` is repeated in foreach loop php

```
<div class="bus" id="result1">
  <div class="seat red" data-number="A4(W)" data-book="1" amount="505" uniq-id="1452746805">
  </div>
  <div class="seat red" data-number="B4(W)" data-book="1" amount="505" uniq-id="1452746801">
  </div>
  <div class="seat red" data-number="C4(W)" data-book="1" amount="505" uniq-id="1452746823">
  </div>
  <div class="seat red" data-number="D4(W)" data-book="1" amount="505" uniq-id="1452746839">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bus" id="result2">
  <div class="seat red" data-number="A4(W)" data-book="1" amount="501" uniq-id="1452746803">
  </div>
  <div class="seat red" data-number="B4(W)" data-book="1" amount="505" uniq-id="1452746802">
  </div>
  <div class="seat red" data-number="C4(W)" data-book="1" amount="505" uniq-id="1452746804">
  </div>
  <div class="seat red" data-number="D4(W)" data-book="1" amount="505" uniq-id="1452746801">
  </div>
</div>
  .....
  .....
  <div class="bus" id="resultn">
     .....
     ....
  </div>
```

when click on a div with  class `seat`  a class `green` is added to it
i want count the `green` classes in each div with class `bus`.
Here is my code

```
$(document).on("click",".seat",function(){
   var total_class = $('.green').length;
})
```

Problem is i am getting total number of `green` class from all divs with  class `bus`

**UPDATE**

when click on a div with class seat i want to put data-number attribute value to an array for each class bus separately,later it is used for some db operations.

Here is my code

```
$(document).on("click",".seat",function(){

  var temp=[];
  var seat_no = $(this).attr("data-number");
  temp.push(seat_no);

}
```

Problem is i am getting all the data-number attribute from from all divs with class bus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) method to access the parent on that element you clicked, so you can get the number of instances for class .green

```
var total_class = 0;    

$(document).on("click",".seat",function(){
    total_class = $(this).parent().children('.green').length
})
```

Comment: great that it solves your problem. About the update, if this is a new question please consider posting a new separate topic on this. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

In this case

1. you need select the parent of the element that was click which is
   the `.bus` in your case.
2. from the parent find its children that has a class of `.green` and get its count

that is what I did in this code :

```
var total_class = $(this).parent('.bus').children('.green').length;
```

**DEMO:**

```js
    $(document).on("click", ".seat", function() {
      $(this).addClass('green');
      var total_class = $(this).parent('.bus').children('.green').length;
      alert(total_class);
    })
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
.green {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bus" id="result1">
  <div class="seat red" data-number="A4(W)" data-book="1" amount="505" uniq-id="1452746805">b1
  </div>
  <div class="seat red" data-number="B4(W)" data-book="1" amount="505" uniq-id="1452746801">b1
  </div>
  <div class="seat red" data-number="C4(W)" data-book="1" amount="505" uniq-id="1452746823">b1
  </div>
  <div class="seat red" data-number="D4(W)" data-book="1" amount="505" uniq-id="1452746839">b1
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="bus" id="result2">
  <div class="seat red" data-number="A4(W)" data-book="1" amount="501" uniq-id="1452746803">b2
  </div>
  <div class="seat red" data-number="B4(W)" data-book="1" amount="505" uniq-id="1452746802">b2
  </div>
  <div class="seat red" data-number="C4(W)" data-book="1" amount="505" uniq-id="1452746804">b2
  </div>
  <div class="seat red" data-number="D4(W)" data-book="1" amount="505" uniq-id="1452746801">b2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click",".seat",function(){
   var total_class = $(this).closest(".bus").find('.green').length;
})
```

This will give you total divs with class green in same bus

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(document).on("click",".seat",function(){
    var total_class = $(this).parent().find('.green').length;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
           $('.seat').click(function () {
           $(this).addClass('green');
          // $('#total').val($('.bus').find('div.green').length);

           szTotal = $('.bus').find('div.green').length;

           szResult = "Total no of green class in current div (id=" + $(this).closest('div.bus').attr('id') + ") = " + $(this).closest('div.bus').find('div.green').length

           szResult = szResult + "<br>" + "Total green class in All Div=" + szTotal

           alert(szResult)
       });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.seat').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass('green');
        get_number_with_class('green');
    });
});

function get_number_with_class(classname)
{
    var total_class = $('div.'+classname).length;
}
```

that worked for me